# Can women pray in public, like men?

Tags: salat, women

Asalamu-alaikum,

When we are travelling, men often find mosques or pray in the public. (This is when shortening the prayer is not an option). But for women, how can they manage?

Many scholars suggest, women to stay at home or plan the journey in such a manner. Practically it is not always possible. And in many mosques there is no place for women to pray. So I read this [question](https://islamqa.info/en/21869) in islamqa.
It says women can pray in the ground in any place. Does that mean they can pray in public, where other men can look at them? Is that correct? How did the wives of the Prophet (PBUH) and his companions do their prayers?

Thanks
Aslam

Comment: These fatwas from the same scholar/site may answer your question to some extent https://islamqa.info/en/95577 https://islamqa.info/en/21803 https://islamqa.info/en/39178

Answer (score 3):

### Can women pray in public, like men?

Yes. It is perfectly halal for women to pray in public. But it is mandatory for women to cover their awrah while praying. So, she should cover herself properly while praying in public.

> It says women can pray in the ground in any place. Does that mean they
>   can pray in public, where other men can look at them? Is that correct?

Yes, it is correct. It is permissible for women to pray in public where other men can look at them. But men should not look at her with lust. They should lower their gaze as stated in the Quran:

> "Say to the believing men that they should lower their gaze and guard
>   their modesty: that will make for greater purity for them: And Allah
>   is well acquainted with all that they do." [Al-Qur’an 24:30]